# summing the positive values of k variables in R

Tags: r, sum, stata

I want to first find a `max of 0 or j` where `j` is any variable and then sum these for k (k=1,2,...k) variables of a dataframe `data`. In `stata`, I did as follows:

```
 gen sum=max(0,x)+max(0,y)+max(0,z)+...+max(0,k)
```

In `R` I used following approach:

```
data$sum<-ifelse(data$x<0,0,data$x*1)+ifelse(data$y<0,0,data$y*1)+ifelse(data$z<0,0,data$z*1)+...+ifelse(data$k<0,0,data$k*1)
```

I was wondering whether there is an alternative and efficient approach in `R` to do the same thing.

Comment: At the end of the day, you are still free to accept whatever answer you want, but please realize you asked a question about how to do something in R.

Comment: @flodel:I did and I am using `R`. I didn't know that I can't check all answers as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mycols   <- c("x", "y", "z", "k")
data$sum <- rowSums(data[mycols] * (data[mycols] > 0))
```

---

Check with some sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(x = runif(10) - 0.5,
                   y = runif(10) - 0.5,
                   z = runif(10) - 0.5,
                   k = runif(10) - 0.5)

identical(rowSums(data[mycols] * (data[mycols] > 0)), # mine
          ifelse(data$x < 0, 0, data$x * 1) +         # yours
          ifelse(data$y < 0, 0, data$y * 1) +
          ifelse(data$z < 0, 0, data$z * 1) +
          ifelse(data$k < 0, 0, data$k * 1))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatives to flodel's excellent solution, noting the first looks quite a bit like your Stata code.

```
with( data,   # terrible name for an R object, BTW
   pmax(x, 0) + pmax(y, 0) + pmax(z, 0) +pmax(k,0) )

rowSums( apply(data[-5], 2, pmax, 0) )
```

The second one is probably slower, but it is in the running for this R-golf competition. Also a matrix math solution:

```
as.matrix( (data[,1:4] > 0 )* data[, 1:4]) %*% rep(1, 4  )
```

Comment: @DWin: Thanks. Unfortunately, the first two didn't give the correct answer (when compared to the my,flodel, and your matrix codes). Can you please edit that?

Comment: The problem in the first case was that I was summing x,y,x,k. The problem in hte second case was that I forgot that there was already a pre-existing "sum" column from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Not the question, but writing out every variable in Stata is likely to be tedious and error-prone. There is likely to be scope for a loop here:

```
gen sum = 0 
quietly foreach v of var varlist { 
    replace sum = sum + `v' if inrange(`v', 0, .) 
}
```

where you must work out what the varlist should be.